# An Untimely Rebus For Your Puzzlement

Tags: word, rebus

[image: The magic of GIF technology!]

> Now with eye-popping graphics! (Hey, it's my first rebus.)
>   Text version:
>   $$
> \begin{matrix}
> light-speed & & & & here\\
> & & ? & & \\
> \end{matrix}
> $$

Comment: Is the `?` part of the rebus?

Comment: @boboquack Yes, the question mark is a part of the rebus. Sorry for the slow response. Posted just before going to bed.

Comment: *untimely*, hmm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be a

> $corpse$  
>  $c$ (speed of light) + $or$ (deciding which ?) + $pse$ (here = pse site)

The title: An untimely rebus may refer to

> - late which has a meaning as a deceased body, or theatrical slang for ill-timed stage behaviour
>
>   - the same answer ['corpse'](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48126/a-riddle-like-a-phoenix) to one of the OP's questions posted the same day - very suspicious!

Comment: Great! You might say the second puzzle rose from the ashes of the first ;)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> CLEFT?

Explanation:

> Light speed is usually denoted by $c$, and the fact that "Here" is on the right indicates that that's our frame of reference, i.e. **c** is on the **left**, giving "cleft".

Comment: Nice, but the question mark is at the heart of the solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: @HughMeyers *Now* I get what you meant by "at the heart of the solution". :)

Comment: @Ankoganit ... as in "slightly to the left of center". ;)

Comment: @HughMeyers You might say it filled the CLEFT in the middle of the solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Is it -

> Future .(as time-travel is there)--thinking about future--

As-

> "Here" is front of "speed of light" , so you have crossed speed of light thus you are in traveling to future i.e time travel

Answer (score 2):

> Rayovac, a famous battery brand

Because

> What is untimely light speed? Absent time its just distance, an infinite ray.  A ray to here over a stick figure with an empty question? The ennui!  It's a ray over a vacuous individual or, to stretch it, 'rayovac'.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

> Nothing to see here

From

> speed of light $c$ = see
>  nothing between it and here

Comment: Another good guess. The answer, however, is a single word.